# Connection not secure with correct SSL certificate(Websockets)

Tags: ssl, websocket, ssl-certificate

The SSL certificate has been correctly issued for `https://www.govtschemes.in`

However I've Websocket servers based on Python and Nodejs which use the same domain(just to save domain+SSL costs) but at different port 31333

So in WebSocket server it binds as : `wss://www.govtschemes.in:31333`

In some Firefox browsers, Websocket client is able to contact those servers without any problem. But with most Firefox browsers they are not. For them I type `https://www.govtschemes.in:31333` in address bar and *confirm security exception*. Then it starts working properly.

As per [Comodo site](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/326/17/can-a-single-ssl-server-certificate-cover-multiple-ports-per-domain-name) SSL certficate will work for multiple ports( 31333).

Then why do I( or my clients ) need to make this security exception for `wss://www.govtschemes.in:31333`  so that Javascript Browser clients code can contact the Websocket remote servers?

[image]

Comment: You are trying to talk HTTP to a server that talks WebSocket. Maybe, it is THE problem. Did you press "Learn more..." to learn more. And try to capture the traffic with wireshark for a better understanding of what went wrong...

Answer (score 0):

This is a misconfiguration of the server. It sends only the leaf certificate but not that chain certificates.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.govtschemes.in:31333
...
Certificate chain
  0 s:CN = govtschemes.in
    i:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
```

Contrary to this the server in port 443 (i.e. default https) sends everything:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.govtschemes.in:443
...
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = govtschemes.in
   i:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
   i:C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
```

Note that just because you use the same certificate on different servers does not mean that the SSL connection to the servers will behave the same. These are different servers which serve different certificate chains and also support different TLS versions.

Comment: Who should send the chain certificate? My Nodejs Websocket based server?

Comment: @user5858: The certificate chain should be send by the server which is currently not sending the chain and which thus causes problems. This is the server on port 31333, i.e. your Nodejs Websocket server. The server on port 443 is already sending the chain correctly so no need to change this server.